# Any chance I can recover this video file?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, data-recovery

So I had a MOV file I recorded.  It was game-play form a game on my iPod.  I spent forever timing it to music.  Anyway, I saved it to my flashdrive, and plugged that drive into my windows machine where I edited it.

Unfortunately after I got done editing it I had a lapse of logic and decided the file needed to be moved from the flash-drive to my SSD.  Unfortunately for some reason it couldn't delete the original file so it didn't end up working because it couldn't delete the original.

Unfortunately I didn't realize that it meant that the file was still on the flash-drive and not on the PC (I thought it was on both).... so I deleted it!

I have scanned the folder where I think i tried to move it, and there was nothing.  Scanners found the file inside of the flashdrive, however the free recover software (Recuva) restored it as corrupted.

I have tried repair however the software just said "unsupported file type"....

Comment: There are many file recovery programs out there which may fix this. You'll need to try a few out

Comment: @J.Doe try Recuva

Comment: @iSR5 I did try recuva.  I also tried a mac one.  Both can get the file out, however they can not fix it and thus it cant be read.... I dont really understand how video files work... but how come it isnt possible to grab out groups of frames?

Comment: @J.Doe the file might be corrupted when you deleted it. The file recovery software will recover the deleted file in which state has been deleted, so if the file was corrupted somehow, and then you deleted it, you'll end up recovering the corrupted file with no use.

Comment: @J.Doe try to recover the file first, no matter its state, then try to repair its codec if there is any problem with the codec, see if this will work with you. Sometimes, videos lose their codec or their codecs missed up in recovery process, and it needs to be rebuild by some special software. google "MOV codec repair".

Comment: You say that *it couldn't delete the original file* initially. Was that because it was still open in a program at that time? **If not** that is a strong indicator that there was already corruption at that time. In that case there's not much you can do.